# Активная кнопка фильтрации по тегу! Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Не могу понять как реализовать подсвечивание выбранную кнопку, которая будет делать фильтрацию по списку - тег!
Ранее я использовал моковые данные прям в компоненте, и тогда у меня было поле active: true, ну и я менял состояние все прекрасно.

Но сейчас с API получаю список тегов, и из state забираю список в котором есть поля:
name, id.

И как же теперь привязыватся к конкретному элементу не пойму(((

```
<div v-for="item in tagsList" :key="item.id" class="swiper-slide">
          <AppButton
            blog-tag-btn
            class="swiper-slide-btn"
            :blog-tag-btn-active="isActive"
            @click="selectTag(item.id)"
          >
            {{ item.name }}
          </AppButton>
        </div>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      slider: null,
      isActive: false,
    }
  },

methods: {
    selectTag(id) {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
      this.$emit('select-tag', id)
    },
  },
```

если я сделаю вот так, то будут подсвечивался сразу все кнопки из моего списка, а не конкретная!
В этом примере локальная переменная не спасет, а вот нужно какое-то условие, которое будет учитывать уникальность каждой кнопки, а уникальность эту дает id, я когда так уже делал, но вот совсем как обило(

Comment: А вот это свойство `blog-tag-btn-active`, которому ты биндишь значение `null` - оно не "активностью" кнопки управляет? И еще, если это "подсвечивание" должно быть только визуальным - то почему бы не реализовать его как обычно, условным биндом класса (и стилизовать через CSS)? Опиши проблему более подробно, пожалуйста. Отредактировать вопрос можно нажав на текстовую кнопку "Править" под ним.

Comment: @yar85
Вот добавил немного развернутый вопрос!))
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() { return {
    tagsList: [],
    isActive: {},
  }},
  methods: {
    selectTag(id) {
      this.$set(this.isActive, id, !this.isActive[id]);
      this.$emit('select-tag', id);
    },
    fetchItems() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(r => r.json()).then(data => this.tagsList = data);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchItems();
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide { display: inline-block; margin: 0.25rem; }
.swiper-slide-btn { padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem; }
.swiper-slide-btn.active { background: #acf; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in tagsList" :key="item.id" class="swiper-slide">
    <button class="swiper-slide-btn"
      :class="{ active: isActive[item.id] }"
      @click="selectTag(item.id)"
    >
      {{ item.name }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
```

На что тут следует обратить внимание:

1. `isActive: {},`
   Это свойство должно содержать структуру, а не одиночное булевое значение - ведь переключаемый элемент у нас не один, их несколько. Обычный объект для такой задачи вполне хорошо подходит.
2. `this.$set(this.isActive, id, !this.isActive[id]);`
   Присваивание нового состояния флага выполняется через метод `$set`, потому что Vue не имеет возможности автоматически отслеживать добавление новых свойств в объекты.
   Если просто присваивать `this.isActive[id] = !this.isActive[id]`, то реактивных обновлений не будет, ведь изначально объект `isActive` пуст, и Vue "не увидит" в нем появлений новых свойств `[id]`.
3. `:class="{ active: isActive[item.id] }"`
   Бинд класса здесь имеет очень простую логику - класс `active` (через который кнопки и стилизуются) добавляется элементу когда `isActive[item.id]` принимает значение `true`.
   А что при значении `undefined`, когда кнопка еще не переключалась? Тоже просто: здесь Vue автоматически приводит `undefined` к булевому `false`, и соотв., класс не добавляется - именно то, что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!!!
Сейчас переделаю!
Очень вам боагодарен!

Comment: @AlexanderMilovanov, пожалуйста!

Comment: А может вы еще мне подскажите, а как тогда в там случае
Лучше проводить проверку на количество активных ссылок?
`
Object.keys(this.isActive).length
`
Я сперва подумал что можно так

Comment: selectTag(id) {
      if (Object.keys(this.isActive).length <= 2) {
        this.$set(this.isActive, id, !this.isActive[id])
        this.$emit('select-tag', id)
      } else {
        this.isActive[id] = false
      }
    },

Comment: Вот так попробовал, но там наблюдается засада))

Comment: _«количество активных ссылок»_ - `Object.values(this.isActive).filter(v => v).length`

Comment: Спасибо большое, я так и отложил этот момент. Что-то мой вариант так и не переписался во что-то более рабочее, временно заколхозил на disabled кнопки. Завтра допишу!)) спасибо еще раз!))