# Кто знает, как сделать чтоб при клике на v-alert не открывались все алерты, а только выбранный?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Кто знает, как сделать чтоб при клике на v-alert не открывались все алерты, а только выбранный?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <template v-slot:item.Description="{ value }">
        <div>
          <v-alert
            v-model="alert"
            border="top"
            close-text="Close Alert"
            color="#2a8bfa"
            dismissible
            outlined
            class="ma-2"
            max-width="500"
          >
            {{ value }}
          </v-alert>
          <div class="text-start">
            <v-btn
              v-if="!alert"
              color="#2a8bfa"
              dark
              @click="alert = true"
              outlined
            >
              details
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
```

Data

```
alert: false,
```

Проблема в том что я не прохожусь v-for а, использую v-data-table который сам берет значения.

Comment: Значение-то одно общее (в директиве `v-if`) - так с чего бы не всем сразу открываться? Когда напишешь условие по локальным данным таблицы (или по выражению с индексом строки таблицы), тогда и алерты будут открываться раздельно.

Comment: Похожее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1296031/288409

Comment: @yar85 Благодарю, попробую получить индекс строки таблицы) Понять бы как его взять еще))

Comment: Индекс передается в слот item'а, в документации вьютифая об этом написано (см. описание API `v-data-table`).

Comment: @yar85 ок)) спасибо! Нужно действительно научится мне понимать доку)

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-item - именно в item индекс передается, а в слоты оказывается нет. Так что имеет смысл в сами объекты данных добавлять какой-то уникальный идентификатор, вместо того чтобы переписывать весь рендеринг строки таблицы (либо использовать объекты данных как ключи в `Map` булевых значений показа алертов, либо написать метод и использовать событие компонента для показа алерта. Куча путей решения, в общем. Вариант с методом показа алерта по событию от компонента, мне видится самым рациональным).

Comment: _«Вариант с методом показа алерта по событию от компонента»_ - то есть, я бы добавил в шаблон **один** компонент `v-alert`, по событию из таблицы меняя его содержимое через модель, и ставя флажок отображения в `true`. Это если не надо сразу несколько алертов показывать одновременно.

Comment: @yar85 ок)) Благодарю. Сейчас попробую)

Comment: @yar85 у меня получается он дублирует все алерты, один не дает использовать. Потому что его нужно ведь только в template указать с именем v-slot, иначе он вообще не отобразится, а так как указываю в template то, и получается что они дублируются

Comment: Если что-то конкретное не получается, то вoпрос можно редактировать пока ответов нет - участникам надо видеть проблему, детали о возникших трудностях. На данный момент, в вoпросе не видно определенной проблемы (есть только общая/неопределенная задача которую можно десятком различных способов решать), и поэтому невозможно дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: Если нужно показывать один алерт одновременно, то не надо его в слоты строки таблицы совать - ведь эти слоты рендерятся в цикле по данным, а компонент алерта в таком случае нужен всего один (соотв., тогда нет смысла его в цикле размножать). Если же надо сразу несколько алертов показывать, то да, тогда слот из итерации по данным может быть полезен... но даже в этом случае, далеко не факт что надо создавать столько алертов сколько в таблице строк. Исходи из своей задачи, ведь я эту задачу не вижу, и поэтому не могу обо всем за тебя думать. Ну и практически пробовать разные варианты надо, конечно

Comment: @yar85 да, задачу все таки решил, правда не знаю правильно или нет, но результат, тот что нужен получил. Я при клике пушу value (т.е текст) в массив, если он уже там есть удаляю его из массива. А, на alert навесил условие  v-if="alertMeaning.includes(value)" и теперь он отображается только если в массиве есть значение, при повторном клике значение стирается и соответственно уже не отображается

Comment: _«пушу value (т.е текст) в массив, если он уже там есть удаляю его из массива»_ - `Map` или простой объект с булевыми флагами в значениях был бы рациональнее (т.к. операции поиска в массиве и изменения его элементов относительно медленные). Пример с простым объектом я скидывал первой ссылкой в комментах. Но если решение через массив устраивает, то почему бы и нет :)

Comment: @yar85 Большое спасибо. Если честно рад что вообще хоть как то решил)) Вроде какие то знания и есть, но туго идут решения. Хочется уже на автомате как Вы различные варианты генерировать и спокойно решать)

Comment: Ну, способность генерировать варианты сама приходит когда от нее начинает зависеть "покушаем в следующем месяце, или нет"))) То есть, с более реальной практикой, и мотивацией определенного рода. Имхо, такие учебные задачи сами по себе ничего не дадут... они могут быть полезны только для закрепления теории, но не в отрыве от нее. Поэтому рекомендую особо не возиться с вьютифаем и прочими библиотеками, т.к. они отвлекают от главного (от задач программирования, от анализа задач и составления алгоритмов их решений), и являются всего лишь заменяемыми инструментами.

Comment: @yar85 да, полностью согласен. Просто проект учебный доделываю для портфолио, осталось уже пару деталей.